# Help writing leds user space driver for HP 17-by4xxx laptop keyboard backlight running Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: drivers, keyboard, hp, backlight

I need to create a new led user space driver for the keyboard backlight on my HP laptop running Ubuntu 23.10. I have found the location for the keyboard drivers.
[device driver directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wU4w.png)
/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3
The current drivers show input3::device_name and I need a new one named input3::kbd_backlight to drive the keyboard backlight which works using the f5 key. I have found the linux documentation for user space leds drivers along with the c program examples, uledmon.c.
I have tried creating the new driver input3::kbd_backlight but I simply don’t understand what I’m doing wrong because even with using sudo I can’t write anything to the input directory. The documentation and videos I could find are not specific enough to cover the directory structure with my Ubuntu distro. I would greatly appreciate any help the community could offer me in learning how to create a new input driver for my keyboard backlight.  Thank You.

Comment: Your question could *really* use some formatting like paragraphs and highlighting and so on. Such an edit could really improve your question and boost the likeliness of a good answer.

Comment: `/sys` is not a normal directory. It's a kernel interface. If you want to add things to `/sys` you need to add it to the kernel. Thus, it's unlikely that you're just missing user space component, you are likely missing kernel support as well.

Comment: Being a bit pretentious? First thing to do is correct a newbie on formatting? Thanks, with these answers I am totally clear on what to do to fix the problem.